# (my)SQL: query of 2 times the same table with different data to a specific column

Tags: mysql

I am still a bit new but I would like the following result out of the query:

**Input table**:

| ID | Name | Date 1 | Date 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1-2-2023 | 1-5-2023 |
| 2 | B | 2-2-2023 | 2-5-2023 |
| 3 | C | 3-2-2023 | 3-5-2023 |

**Expected Output**:

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1-2-2023 |
| 2 | B | 2-2-2023 |
| 3 | C | 3-2-2023 |
| 1 | A | 1-5-2023 |
| 2 | B | 2-5-2023 |
| 3 | C | 3-5-2023 |

I have made the database in MySQL but I'm struggling with the query.
(as specially joining 1 table with it self like this)

How can I make a query results as above?

Comment: You have **one** table. Why are you talking about "* joining 2 tables*"? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: Your result looks like a a `UNION` of two `SELECT` queries.

Comment: yes, `select id, name, date1 as Date union all select id, name, date2 as date;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *union* your queries - this works by "stacking" the results on top of each other, allowing us to choose the date column from each.

By adding a *source* column we can union them in a derived table and use it to provide for ordering the data as shown.

```
select Id, Name, Date
from (
    select Id, Name, Date1 Date, 1 Source 
    from t
    union all
    select Id, Name, Date2, 2 Source 
    from t
)t
order by Source, Id;
```

See a [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2-xNBxhU)